# What do we mean by 'persistence' in the context of ORMs?

Tags: orm, mongoid

I'm new to the world of ORMs/ODMs. The word 'persistence' is used often. What do we mean by 'persistence'?

Comment: [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistence_(computer_science)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Persistence is the process of persisting(storing) data into the database, so the data outlives the application process. It is not unique to `ORM`. It is just a term for storing data.